# C++ Win32 Window unresponsive

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a console application from which I create a window.

I can render stuff in the window just fine. But the window is unresponsive/uncontrollable by the user.

As soon as you mouse over the window you get the hourglass cursor and cannot move the window.

What might be causing this?

EDIT:

```
    WNDCLASSEX wndClass;         // Window class
    ZeroMemory(&wndClass, sizeof(wndClass)); // Clear the window class structure
    wndClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX); 
    wndClass.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_CLASSDC;
    wndClass.lpfnWndProc    = DefWindowProc;
    wndClass.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wndClass.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wndClass.hInstance      = nullptr;
    wndClass.hCursor        = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wndClass.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wndClass.lpszMenuName   = NULL;//MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MAINMENU);
    wndClass.lpszClassName  = _classname.c_str();
    wndClass.hIconSm        = 0;

    if (RegisterClassEx(&wndClass) == 0)// Attemp to register the window class
        throw std::exception("WINDOW ERROR: Failed to register the window class!");

    DWORD dwStyle = 0;              // Window styles
    DWORD dwExStyle = 0;            // Extended window styles

    dwStyle = WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW |        // Creates an overlapping window
              WS_CLIPCHILDREN |            // Doesn"t draw within child windows
              WS_CLIPSIBLINGS;              // Doesn"t draw within sibling windows

    //adjust window size
    RECT rMain;
    rMain.left = 0;
    rMain.right = width;
    rMain.top = 0;
    rMain.bottom = height;  

    AdjustWindowRect(&rMain, dwStyle, 0);

    // Attempt to create the actual window
    _hwnd = CreateWindowEx( dwExStyle,     
                            className,
                            windowTitle,      
                            dwStyle,         
                            0, 0,           
                            rMain.right - rMain.left,
                            rMain.bottom - rMain.top,  
                            nullptr,             
                            0,  
                            nullptr,
                            0); 


    ShowWindow(_hwnd, SW_SHOW);
    SetForegroundWindow(_hwnd);
    SetFocus(_hwnd);
```

Comment: It would be extremely helpful if you had a (minimal) code snippet that demonstrates this problem.

Comment: Do you handle WM_MOUSE* messages in your WindowProc?

Comment: I don't handle anything I just use DefWindowProc.

Comment: What does your code do after the window is created? Most likely the issue is in your message loop.

Comment: Please show your message pumping loop

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Since it's already mentioned in comments, I'll make this community wiki*

You need to get the messages for the window and dispatch them accordingly.

```
/* 
 *  HWND hWnd: this is the handle to your window (that is returned from CreateWindow[Ex]
*/
MSG msg;
while (GetMessage(&msg, hWnd, NULL, NULL) > 0){
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

If you don't do this, your `wndProc` function will never get any messages, and Windows finds it unresponsive (thus the hourglass).

Answer (score 0):

A part of the message loop had been "temporarily" commented away and I missed this.